# svn merge entire directories in conflict

Tags: svn

I'm in a bit of a pickle, a designer created a branch in SVN and instead of copying files from the trunk, pulled them down from a FTP server.  Now - when I go to merge the branch back into the trunk. I'm getting conflicts on entire directories and not individual files.

all the errors are

```
C dir
> local add, incoming add upon merge
```

Is there a way to tell SVN to be ok w/ these directories but compare the files in the directories?

Here is my current merge cmd in the trunk checkout:

```
svn merge -r45759:HEAD svn://path/to/branch
```

These are the first 3 commits in the branch if they help

- revision 45759 is when the branch was created
- revision 45797 is the checkin from pulling files down from FTP and
  committing them to the branch
- revision 45823 is the first actual
  change on the branch committed

Comment: Is there a special reason to use that complicated svn merge command instead of simply "svn merge svn://path/to/branch" ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to redo the merge via

```
svn merge --accept theirs-full svn://path/to/branch
```

which will get all the changes from the branch without asking..just using them...but be carefull, cause you have already created a folder dir in your local working copy which produces the conflict...